T-GDI vs NA Petrol Cruising characteristics
I am interested in the real world applicability of vehicles' real world cruising RPMs. Consider two cars' Power Curves:

1.5L MPFI NA Petrol ~ 30hp @ 2000rpm @ 6th gear ~ 1150kg kerb wt ~ runs at 80kph 25% throttle
1.5L Turbo GDI      ~ 60hp @ 2000rpm @ 6th gear ~ 1250kg kerb wt ~ runs at 95kph 20% throttle
Both cars are variants of the same car with minor differences in suspension and no change in gear ratios, wheel & tyre size and same cylinder compression 10.5:1.

Shouldn't the 2nd car run significantly faster at this power or conversely shouldn't the rpms be significantly lower? The fuel consumption is quite similar at around 22km/l and 21km/l respectively, I conclude accounting for the turbo's fuel dumping to prevent knock/LSPI - the turbo is a VGT that achieves peak torque ~185ft-lb/250Nm at 1500 rpm.
What am I missing here? Is the power difference solely due to insignificant power difference at part throttle? Is the T-GDI only significantly powerful at full throttle?

vehicle power curves are set at wide open throttle.    It is almost impossible to compare two engines at different throttle positions.

Worse than that, the throttle on a diesel is doing something entirely different (fuel rate) to the throttle on a petrol car (butterfly flap angle)
